# Getting/Setting file permission on IIS

Tags: php, iis, permissions

I am running PHP5 on IIS7. When I use the functions `fileperms` and `chmod` they do not work as expected. I know that some installations are setup to work, however, mine is not. Is there an alternative for getting and setting permissions Windows?

Comment: Yes, **[XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)**

Comment: Paid webhost, can't make changes like that. However, I like that for my personal server at home.

Comment: Why would you pay for a windows server with IIS to host a PHP script? they're usually more expensive than plain Apache servers.

Comment: The group I built the site for was already using an Access database, so I needed Jet. They weren't willing to switch to MySQL for various reasons, and since the database isn't very big, and will never get that big, it actually runs faster than MySQL currently (as I made a copy of the site running from MySQL for testing). Plus, the hosting costs are actually quite reasonable.